# Get/set data from/to input field in assets HTML file?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-assets

A `WebView` loads HTML page from the `/assets` dir. When a user enters some data into a text field in that HTML file, can my `WebView` catch/save that data once a user preses some button or link?

Also, when a user returns to that page, can I fill the text field with the data he previously entered?

I am trying to create a way to save temporary data between HTML pages in /assets dir.